# Old gradle projet issue

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I am reading a Kotlin book that has the following repository:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Building-Applications-with-Spring-5-and-Kotlin/tree/master

It contains several projects, all of them with build.gradle, whenever I try to run one in intellij I get all sorts of errors,

I have tried changing SDK, kotlin version, dependencies version, running from the terminal, nothing has worked for me...

Am I missing some extra step? I know the repo is old and even the syntax for the build.gradle, but maybe there is something more... Or do I have to update every line in that file?

I have never used gradle. Can someone try to execute one of those projects?